# Unfortunately, App has stopped - E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner in using Android Studio and my english not so good.

I'm developing an app web view. While i test my app this error appear "Unfortunately app has stopped".

Can anyone help me...plz....here the code.Thanks in advance.

MainActivity

```
package com.xxx.xxx.xxx;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("https://xxx.xxxx.xxx");

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx.xxx">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.blogspot.xxx.xxxx.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" >
    </WebView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

> 09-16 21:34:52.168 15207-15207/com.xxx.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.xxx.xxx.xxx, PID: 15207
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.xxx.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be
>   set before loadAd is called.
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.
>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzez.zzfd(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzez.zza(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
>       at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: You have to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` before you can reference the layout.

Comment: What is not clear in `The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.`?

Comment: @TDG Thank you, that solve the problem..

Comment: @ModularSynth Sorry..

Comment: You don't need to feel sorry. You need to pay attention to your error messages. They try to tell you a way to solve your issue. Sometimes very explicitly, as in this case

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the size of your add and the id of it modify your java code some thing like this

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    mAdView.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```